# Mysql : table strucutre design for post 'like' and 'unlike'

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, database-design

I have an android app which a user can `"like/unlike"` a post,

I have created a table:

```
| id | post_id | user_id |
|  1 |     105 |      67 |
|  2 |      76 |      56 |
|  3 |      36 |     102 |
```

with id auto-increment, is this table structure correct?

since one person can like/dislike multiple times, do you think deleting the row (unlike) + create new row (like) is good practice?

The auto-increment row will increase and reached big numbers if there are many users, is this bad? since the auto-increment cannot reuse the deleted row.

if I added an extra `boolean` column, `like` with value `1` or `0`

and consider a user without an existing row in the table + 
user with an existing row but column `like = 0` as unlike

will that be better?

Comment: Do you use the auto-incrementing column for anything? Why not just use a composite primary key between post_id and user_id?

Comment: That really depends on the purpose of this table. Do you want to monitor history?

Answer (score 0):

> do you think deleting the row (unlike) + create new row (like) is good practice?

This design has a flaw. Suppose, the user has unliked. But there is no corresponding row in the table for him. So there is nothing to delete.

You won't be able to store the information about unlikes.

> The auto-increment row will increase and reached big numbers if there are many users, is this bad?

You don't need an auto increment column here. Use a compound primary key:

```
post_id - PK, FK to posts table
user_id - PK, FK to users table
like - boolean (0 - dislike, 1 -like)
```

In this case you'll be able to store all the information. And you are protected from the auto increment column expiration.

#### Update

IF you don't need to keep unlike value for the post, and the user can't unlike the post before he liked it. The easiest solution would be to create a simple mapping table:

```
post_id - PK, FK to posts table
user_id - PK, FK to users table
```

When the user liked the post, add a row. IF he unliked, delete the row.

Comment: so If a user "unlike", should I keep the column?
or is it easier just to add another "like" column with value 1 or 0? 
so when a user "liked" first time, it create a new row, later if he "unliked", will keep the column but set the "like" column value to 0. I dont have to keep track of the "unlike", so "unlike" will be non-exist row or "like" column of row = 0

Answer (score 0):

**Simple like**

```
 Create table like( 
    user_id int,
    post_id int,
    Constraint pk_like primary key (user_id, post_id),
    Constraint fk_user foreign key (user_id) references UserTable(id),
    Constraint fk_post foreign key (post_id) references PostTable(id)
 );
```

If user does like you add a row,

```
Insert into like values (@userId,@postId);
```

If he disslike his like you delete

```
Delete from like where user_id = @userId and post_id = @post_id;
```

**If the "unlike" exist in your app, you should add a bool column 1 if like and 0 if is unlike, if you have more than like and disslike, example: hate, love, ungry.**

```
#Call in query to like(1), unlike(2), hate(3)
call sp_Like(@userID,@postId,1); 
#To dont like,unlike,hate,etc anymore you send (-1) in likeType.
call sp_Like(@userID,@postId,-1);
    #This is your query
    call sp_Like(@userID,@postId,likeType);

    Create table yourDB.like( 
    user_id int,
    post_id int,
    likeType int,
    Constraint pk_like primary key (user_id, post_id),
    Constraint fk_user foreign key (user_id) references UserTable(id),
    Constraint fk_post foreign key (post_id) references PostTable(id)
    );


    DELIMITER $$
    USE yourDB$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS yourDB.sp_Like$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE yourDB.sp_Like
    (
      IN ruser_id int,
      IN rpost_id int,
      IN rlikeType int
    )
    BEGIN
    DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
          BEGIN
          ROLLBACK;
          SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1;
          select "-1" as "response";
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;

    #check if he done like before
    If exists(select post_id from like where  user_id = ruser_id and post_id = rpost_id)
    Then
    #if user doesnt like or unlike, love, hate, anymore
    If rlikeType = -1 then delete from like where 
    user_id = ruser_id and post_id = rpost_id; 
    else
    #if user change like type
    Update like set likeType = rlikeType where  user_id = ruser_id and post_id = rpost_id;
    end if;

    Else
    #if he doesnt like yet
    Insert into like values (ruser_id,rpost_id,rlikeType);
    End if;

    select "1" as "response";
    COMMIT;

    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```